# Animated fantasy show about young man who defends a dinosaur kingdom from evil

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, dinosaurs

1. There is a city or kingdom inhabited by dinosaurs.
2. MC is a young man (perhaps a prince) who defends this kingdom from the armies of evil. There was a battle scene where he flew on a pterodactyl during a thunderstorm and killed monsters, he probably had his allies with him, but I can’t remember anything about them.
3. The armies of evil consisted of lizardmen, ape-men, skeletons, and possibly some type of goblin.
4. The main antagonists and leaders of the evil armies were a Vampire-like sorceress in black clothes and an evil lord in red armor, with green skin and (possibly) a long beard.
5. There was another character - an anthropomorphic dog knight who rode a giant snail and got into ridiculous situations.

I saw this around 2010-2012, According to the animation style, this is maybe something from the 80s or 90s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [*The Prince of Dinosaurs*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5493684/) (2000).

> Join Rakhal, Prince of the Land of Ice, and his five dinosaur friends
> on a journey to find the meaning of an ancient parchment. The friends
> must free Princess Aura and bring peace back to the land in this high
> quality animated feature.

You can see Sir Braveheart (the dog) riding Sluggard, the giant snail in the video below:

> 

Comment: https://mondo-world.fandom.com/wiki/The_Prince_of_Dinosaurs

Comment: Thank you, it is.